# How to send Firebase Cloud Messaging notification based on user property, user audiences

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Using Firebase Admin API how to send notification based on user property, user audiences also App Version.

In console send notification based on user property, user audiences also App Version is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no feature to send notifications to users with specific properties/part of a user audience/app version via the Firebase Admin nor the REST API.